# Authorization in Microfrontends

Tags: angular, authentication, authorization, token, micro-frontend

Currently transforming my application into a microfrontend approach.
Therefore looking for an advice regarding how to handle the Authorization / Authentication for the Microfrontends.

What is the best practice for Authorization / Authentication for a shared Microfrontend? 
How should the Shells load / call the Microfrontend with the required permissions?

The architecture looks like following.
[image]

Comment: Hi, i am in the same position, converting an existing application into a microfront end. Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: I am also facing same requirements? Have you got any way-out around this?